# ASP.NET Localization Not Working for me

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms

I know I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but I can't quite figure it out...

I have 2 resource files in my App_GlobalResources folder: Global.resx and Global.fr-CA.resx.

I have the following label on my webform:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, Test %>" />
```

When I run the form, it displays the value correctly from Global.resx.  Now, in code-behind, I want to manually change the culture to pull from my fr-CA resx file:

```
Page.UICulture = "fr";
Page.Culture = "fr-CA";
```

However, when I re-run the app it doesn't pull the value from Global.fr-CA.resx - it still pulls from Global.resx.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the [InitializeCulture()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) method of your page class and set both `Page.Culture` and `Page.UICulture` to the specific culture `fr-CA`:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    base.InitializeCulture();
    Page.Culture = Page.UICulture = "fr-CA";
}
```

Comment: What's the neutral culture of your assembly?

Comment: So you have english strings in your `Global.resx` file? Does it help if you also set `Page.UICulture` to `fr-CA`?

Comment: Blamo - that worked!  I tried that before I moved it to the override InitializeCulture().  If you edit your answer I'll accept it.